# Connects a virtual network adapter to a virtual switch

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

How can connect a virtual switch to a virtual machine from powershell by Ids?

I tried:

```
# get virtual machine object
$vm = get-vm -Id '...id...'

# get virtual switch object
$vs = get-switch -Id '...id...'

# connect both
connect-vmnetworkadapter -vm $vm -vmswitch $vs
```

I want to connect VM to VS by Ids because the name is not unique.

I get the error:

```
Connect-VMNetworkAdapter : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'vm'
is ambiguous. Possible match include: -VMName -VMNetworkAdapter -VMSwitch -Name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually rather self-explanatory. The parameter `-VM` is ambiguous, i.e. the [`Connect-VMNetworkAdapter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848496%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) cmdlet has more than one parameter beginning with `VM`. Use the parameter `-VMName` with the name of the VM:

```
Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vm.Name -VMSwitch $vs
```

If you can't use the name you must read the adapter from a pipeline, since AFAICS `Connect-VMNetworkAdapter` doesn't accept VM objects as input.

```
$vm.NetworkAdapters | Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMSwitch $vs
```

You may need to select the right adapter, if the VM has more than one, though.

Comment: It is not the same as Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName 'name' -VMSwitch $vs ? I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify the vm. The name is not unique field.

Comment: In that case you need to work with a pipeline. See updated answer.